# robocopy move a file from multiple folders

Tags: powershell, robocopy

so i had created a powershell script that move a specific file called append on our pdas to our server that are being uploaded to our database and then deletes the append

but on one of our computers the user have 3 pdas that he plug in 1 at a the time and synch it 
depending on which one he plugged in the append will apear  in one of thoose 3
    `C:\Users\sindaivan\Documents\Dokumenter på Enhed (Asbjørn)`    `C:\Users\sindaivan\Documents\Dokumenter på Enhed (Ivan)`
    `C:\Users\sindaivan\Documents\Dokumenter på Enhed (Opmærkning)`

so i want it to look in too thoose 3 folders for the append and mirror that folder to dest1 and then move it too dest2 and give me a log of it

```
$dato = get-date -f yyyy-MMM-dd-HH-mm

$data1 = "C:\Users\sindaivan\Documents\"

$dest1 = "X:\ISTAB.Data\Users\SCANNER BACKUP\IVAN\$dato"

$dest2 = "X:\ISTAB.Data\Users\IVAN\"

$logback = "C:\Users\sindaivan\Desktop\Logs\Desktop\LOGS\Backup_log.txt"
$logappend = "C:\Users\sindaivan\Desktop\Logs\Append_import_log.txt"

Robocopy "$data1" "$dest1" /MIR /log:"$logback"

Robocopy "$data1" "$dest2" "append.txt"/MOV /log:"$logappend" 


Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\sindaivan\Documents\*" -Include append.txt -Recurse -Force | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Comment: okay. and what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
$data1 = gci "C:\Users\sindaivan\Documents\"

if(test-path $dest1\append.txt){
     copy-item $data1\append.txt -destination $dest1 -passthru
}
```

Please state a question next time, as nobody is sure if you are asking for help or just trying to post your work. Not sure if robocopy creates folders on the fly, but I know copy-item does so your date folder can work there.